# Train schedule search algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, search, data-structures

I'm trying to solve a problem where trains run between Paris and Berlin every alternate day. A train is considered as "new" if it was NOT running on T-2 day and "ended" if is NOT schedule to run for T+2 day. The departure time of these trains can be (+/-)60 mins with the reference train (with whom we are comparing).

So if I have a dataset for a month, I have to calculate for each trip if it is new or ended. Data is in `trip_id, start_city_id, end_city_id, dep_datetime` format.

Example

```
1,B,P,2018-04-01 07:50  
2,B,P,2018-04-01 13:10  
3,B,P,2018-04-01 15:40  
4,B,P,2018-04-02 08:00  
5,B,P,2018-04-02 12:50  
6,B,P,2018-04-02 15:20  
7,B,P,2018-04-03 09:50  
8,B,P,2018-04-03 13:20  
9,B,P,2018-04-03 15:40  
10,B,P,2018-04-04 09:50  
11,B,P,2018-04-04 13:20  
12,B,P,2018-04-04 14:40
```

In above example=>
* train_id=1 can be considered as "ended" as it is not scheduled to run on T+2 (3rd April) within (+/-)60 mins of time difference to that of train_id=1.
* While train_id=2 can be considered as "no change" as corresponding train runs on 3rd April @12:50 which is within 60 min of the departure time of train_id=2
* while train_id=7 will be considered as "new" train as on T-2 (1st April) there was not corresponding train was running within (+/-)60 mins departure time of train_id=7

I have data in database. 
Right now, I'm looping over each item in the data set and I'm not sure if that is the best approach

1. Do you think I should pull all required data into my program (python) first and run an algorithm on it? Or I should do everything on database itself, may be a stored procedure in MySQL?
2. Which algorithm and data structure should I use?

Comment: Do what''s most convenient for you.

Comment: Do both, and then decide.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Comment: If you have code and it gives you some problem, post it here. What do you mean by "looping over each item"? You have to look at each item at least once, so I probably misunderstand.

Answer (score 0):

Does your method work fast enough? Call it good.

Something like the query below would give the answer (you will need to adjust it to your SQL dialect). Does it work fast enough? Then call it good.

```
select *,
not exists(select * from T T2 
where T2.start_city_id=T.start_city_id
where T2.end_city_id=T.end_city_id
and T2.dep_datetime between T.dep_datetime - '49 hours'::interval and T.dep_datetime  - '47 hours'::interval) as starting,
not exists(select * from T T2 
where T2.start_city_id=T.start_city_id
where T2.end_city_id=T.end_city_id
and T2.dep_datetime between T.dep_datetime + '47 hours'::interval and T.dep_datetime  + '49 hours'::interval) as ending
from T
```

If not, try adding an index on (start_city_id, end_city_id, dep_datetime). Works? Call it good.

If not, try optimising the query. You should be getting a sequential scan and 2 index scans. Works? Call it good.

If all else fails, fetch the data sorted by (start_city_id, end_city_id, dep_datetime), then for each record binary search (in python) for the matching previous or next connection. A little tricky, but should definitely be fast enough.